# Is auto boxing in JavaScript temporarily or permanently?

Tags: javascript, autoboxing

```
let a = 1;
a.toString()
```

When `a.toString()`, a is auto boxing, will become a `Number(1)`, after `a.toString()`, will a be unboxing or not?

Answer (score -1):

`toString()` returns the variable as a string, but does not modify what was originally stored. `typeof a` after calling `toString()` returns "number", as it should.

If you wish for `a` to remain a string after calling `toString()` on it, you can re-assign it as such: `a = a.toString();`

[image: Showing typeof a]

Comment: I think you don't quite understand what they're asking. `autoboxing` is a behind the scenes process in which a number primitive is swapped out for a Number object. Primitives have no properties, meaning `.toString` doesn't exist, and yet you can call `.toString` just fine because when you do the primitive will be automatically replaced with an object. This is invisible to the developer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)#Autoboxing